# Powershell Command in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi

I am trying to query the names all of the WMI classes within the root\CIMV2 namespace. Is there a way to use a powershell command to retrieve this information in C# ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Along the lines of Keith's approach

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var script = @" 
                Get-WmiObject -list -namespace root\cimv2 | Foreach {$_.Name}
            ";

            var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
            powerShell.AddScript(script);

            foreach (var className in powerShell.Invoke())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(className);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure why you mentioned PowerShell; you can do this in pure C# and WMI (the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace, that is).

To get a list of all WMI classes, use the `SELECT * FROM Meta_Class` query:

```
using System.Management;
...

try
{
    EnumerationOptions options = new EnumerationOptions();
    options.ReturnImmediately = true;
    options.Rewindable = false;

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\cimv2", "SELECT * FROM Meta_Class", options);

    ManagementObjectCollection classes = searcher.Get();

    foreach (ManagementClass cls in classes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(cls.ClassPath.ClassName);
    }
}
catch (ManagementException exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would go with Helen's approach and eliminate taking a dependency on PowerShell.  That said, here's how you would code this in C# to use PowerShell to retrieve the desired info:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace RunspaceInvokeExp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var invoker = new RunspaceInvoke())
            {
                string command = @"Get-WmiObject -list -namespace root\cimv2" +
                                  " | Foreach {$_.Name}";
                Collection<PSObject> results = invoker.Invoke(command);
                var classNames = results.Select(ps => (string)ps.BaseObject);
                foreach (var name in classNames)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to note that there is a tool available that allows you to create, run, and save WMI scripts written in PowerShell, the [PowerShell Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/psomatic.mspx) tool, available for download from the [Microsoft TechNet](http://www.microsoft.com/technet) site.

Using this tool, you could explore all of the WMI classes within the root\CIMV2 or any other WMI namespace.

[image: |Image of PowerShell Scriptomatic tool]

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want to just use the System.Management namespace like Helen answered, but you can also host powershell within your application.  See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HowToRunPowerShell.aspx