# How to include string inside another string

Tags: c#, powershell, wmic

I'm trying to run this command using Power shell:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter "DeviceName = 'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator'" | select -ExpandProperty driverversion
```

When running it manually, it works fine, but when I run it via the code, I'm receiving this error:

> Get-WmiObject : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator'.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter DeviceName = 'Microsoft B ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterBindingException
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Here is my code:

```
public static string PlatformModelCommand => $ "Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter \"DeviceName = \'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator\'\" | select -ExpandProperty driverversion";


string projectName = RunCommandUtil.RunPsProcess(PlatformModelCommand);

public static string RunPsProcess(string arguments)
        {
            return RunProcess("powershell.exe", arguments);
        }

public static string RunProcess(string fileName, string arguments) {
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  process.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
  process.Start();
  var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  output += process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
  process.WaitForExit();
  return output;
}
```

Comment: What does `RunPsProcess` do? Why did you post the source of `RunProcess` when that isn't being used? Also, are you running PowerShell in-proc or not?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add one func, edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just want to pass the literal command to PS. If that's so you could drop the [interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) and the single quotes' escaping:

```
public static string PlatformModelCommand => @"""Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter \""DeviceName = 'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator'\"" | select -ExpandProperty driverversion""";
```

**EDIT.**
Since you're passing the command as an argument to powershell.exe, you'll have to escape the inner quotes.
I agree with Luuk in that you might have a better time using [MS's abstractions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) for this problem. There are [some good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56123976/10713658) [examples of that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1933126/10713658) approach on SO as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this in Powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter "DeviceName = \'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerator\'" | select -ExpandProperty driverversion
```

you will also get an error:

```
Get-WmiObject : Invalid query "select * from Win32_PnPSignedDriver where DeviceName = \'Microsoft Bluetooth LE Enumerat
or\'"
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver -filter "DeviceName = \'Microsoft ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I do not know why you did put `\` before the single quotes?

But maybe you should have used [System.Management.Automation.Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.1), which seems to better fit the task ?

Comment: I upvoted this answer because PowerShell should be invoked via `System.Management.Automation.Powershell` instead of `Process`.